# convert from MySql date query to mongoDB date query

Tags: php, mongodb

I used This format in **MySql** to get data in one **week** and in one **mounth**

```
date > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)  // for one week

date > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) // for one month
```

how to convert to php **mongoDB**

Comment: Please provide your attempts and what is wrong with your code. There are many questions on stackoverflow about date ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no native solution. Assuming you are using shell and have collection like this:

```
> db.foo.find({}, {_id: 0})
{ "date" : ISODate("2012-10-06T10:28:10.595Z") }
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-10-01T10:28:14.115Z") }
{ "date" : ISODate("2013-10-16T10:28:19.522Z") }
{ "date" : ISODate("2016-11-04T11:23:00.391Z") }
```

If you want to find all documents with date form last week you can use this code:

```
//Create new date
var weekBefore = new Date((new Date).setDate(new Date().getDate() - 7));
db.foo.find({date: {$gt: weekBefore, $lt: new Date}})
```

If you want to subtract a month you can use (depending on your neeeds) one of below:

```
var monthBefore = new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() - 1))
db.foo.find({date: {$lt: monthBefore}} )
```

or

```
var thirtyOneDaysBefore = new Date(
    (new Date).setDate(new Date().getDate() - 31)
);
db.foo.find({date: {$lt: thirtyOneDaysBefore}})
```

When using driver you have to perform this operations using language native datetime types.